# trying to understand underscore.js

Tags: javascript, return, underscore.js

When going through the underscore.js library, i came across

```
for (var i = 0, l = obj.length; i < l; i++) {
    if (i in obj && iterator.call(context, obj[i], i, obj) === breaker) return;
}

// Establish the object that gets returned to break out of a loop iteration.
breaker = {};
```

why is `return` used at the end? and what does `i in obj` check?

Comment: What function is that in? Perhaps a link to the source?

Comment: Julian Bucknall (CTO of Developer's Express) just recently ran a series of blog posts about understanding underscore.js. I don't have a URL handy, but perhaps you can find a reference to the posts at http://devex.com or via an internet eearch. I'll try and find the link tomorrow and update this comment if you haven't found an answer by then.

Comment: found the link [http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Webinars/details.xml?id=UnderscoreJS](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Webinars/details.xml?id=UnderscoreJS)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`return` exists the function (with the specified return value, if any). This will be covered in a tutorial. In a looping construct it "stops early".

`prop in obj` is an expression that will return true if and only if `obj` (or a chained [[prototype]]) has the property `prop` (with *any* value, including `undefined`). In this case note the values of `i` are over the range `[0, length)`. The result here is "for each *assigned* index in an array".

`iterator` evaluates to a function and is invoked with `call()` so the context (`this` can be set). The special `breaker` variable evaluates to a special sentinel object. For objects, `===` is an "identity equal" and no other new object will `===` the object assigned to `breaker`.

In short: it is a variant of `Array.forEach` (ECMAScript ed. 5) or `jQuery.each` (the utility method) that iterates over a *sparse array*, passes some additional arguments and allows "early termination".

Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like that code loops over some iterator object and breaks when a `breaker` variable has been reached. The `return` statement exits the function.

Answer (score 1):

Note that `breaker` is not something you can use yourself to break out of a `_.each` loop; it's only accessible inside underscore itself and is used internally by the `_.all` and `_.some` methods.